# Avoid users to interact with old contract using Transparent Proxy Pattern

Tags: proxy-contracts

I have a proxy contract that is created with the `Transparent Proxy Pattern`.
If I create a new implementation contract and point the proxy to that it seems that I am still able to call the old contract directly without using the proxy.

As far as I can tell from this [blogpost](https://dev.to/yakult/tutorial-write-upgradeable-smart-contract-proxy-contract-with-openzeppelin-1916) in section `Task 5.4: deploy and interact with BoxV3` under `STEP 3` he is still able to call the old contract even after a new implementation is set up.

I do get that the first implementation contract is on-chain and thereby immutable by itself and cannot be removed - so I actually get that you would be able to still call it directly - but that would also mean that it is not possible to avoid anyone from using the old implementation contract?

The case is that I have a function in the first implementation contract that has an vulnerability. I have fixed this in the second implementation contract and pushed it to the chain and updated the proxy - but what does it matter if someone would just be able to interact directly with the old one?

Comment: what harm can someone do by interacting with your implementation contract directly? It wont' affect any storage/data at your proxy and there shouldn't be anything of value in the implementation address. As long as your proxy now delegatecalls to the new/safe code you're fine

Comment: @sola24 I see, if the data is on the proxy contract, there is no issue. What if I created a contract that isn't a proxy, stored data on that contract and now wants to make use of a proxy contract with the first one as the implementation contract, is that doable? I can I only create a proxy pattern from scratch and not using an existing contract?

Comment: Although not impossible ... I guess there might be some things that could work out OK, but I think there's generally going to be a gotcha somewhere that spoils that plan. e.g. data stored at the wrong contract. The contracts really should be designed/written with the proxy pattern as the intention in the first place.